# Use Proguard 5.3 ,default type methods change to public type

Tags: proguard

I want to develop a private SDK(a jar file),some method is default permission,i want it can be called in current package only,like this:

```
  /* package */
static String getApplicationId() {
    return mApplicationId;
}
```

but,when use proguard to make jar later,this method change to public type,and the method name like this:

```
public static String c() {
    return sApplicationId;
}
```

so i want know how to config proguard file.to make default permission method can't visiable when use this jar by proguard later,thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check your configuration, most likely you have the following setting enabled:

```
-allowaccessmodification
```

When obfuscating a library, you normally do not want this enabled, as you experience the effects as described in the question.